# How to disable the Typescript checks from whole project of React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, eslint

```js
//tslint.json
       
     {
  "defaultSeverity": "error",
  "extends": [
    "tslint:recommended",
    "tslint-config-standard",
    "tslint-react",
    "tslint-config-prettier"
  ],
  "rulesDirectory": ["tslint-plugin-prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier": true,
    "array-type": false,
    "jsx-no-lambda": false,
    "strict-type-predicates": {
      "severity": "warning"
    },
    "jsx-boolean-value": false,
    "no-floating-promises": false
  },
  "globals": {
    "__DEV__": "readonly"
  }
}
```

Creating the build of React project, which has 1000's typescript checks error. I want to disable the all error code. I don't want to put es-lint disable in each file as it's having thousands of typescript errors.

How we can achieve it, with a minimum number of file changes? We want to ignore the typescript check so that during build time...build error would not shown

Project
yarn
typescript - V3.8.2
react- 16.12.0
Note- I am using.tsx & .ts file

Comment: This is an opinion, but using Typescript and ignoring all the errors doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I know this does not make sense. But I will need as hotfix so that we can continue with our automation